# How to create a custom data- attribute in Apine.js?

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I want to create a custom attribute and change the value on click.

I have this:

```
<div x-data="{ colorred = true }" />

    <div @click="colorred = !colorred" />set red state</div>

</div>
```

And it works.

But I would also need to have `data-state-of-color-red="true"` if colorred == true and `data-state-of-color-red="false"` if colorred == false.

So if it colorred is true it will end up like this:

```
<div @click="colorred = !colorred" data-state-of-color-red="true" />set red state</div>
```

otherwise:

```
<div @click="colorred = !colorred" data-state-of-color-red="false" />set red state</div>
```

I am not familiar with Alpine how one create data or any attributes on the fly and how also one changes or toggle their change on the fly.

I reckon that one can chain (using the comma) what is done in @click, so perhaps something like:

```
@click="colorred = !colorred, <and here create/toggle the data- attribute for this element...
```

?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind your data-attribute to the
Alpine variable with the *x-bind* directive or with its short-hand notation using a simple colon before the attribute name:

```html
<div x-data="{ colorred: true }">

    <div @click="colorred = !colorred"
         :data-state-of-color-red="colorred.toString()"
    >
        set red state
    </div>

</div>
```

Here I have used *toString()* to convert the boolean value to a string, otherwise, in case of *false*, the HTML attribute would be removed.

Comment: I am getting "Undefined constant colorred" error. Even in VS Code it has weird color. I know that colorred works, becuase I am using it on the same element like x-show="colorred" and x-show="!colorred" and it works depending on the value true or false.

Comment: Have you copy/pasted my code? In your question the x-data object was malformed you wrote a *=* (equal sign) instead of a *:* (colon), also you have used */>* to close the *div* tags instead of *>*. I've tested my code and it works as espected.

Comment: Yeah, I did it on a div above and it seems to be working.